# Linker error when using unique_ptr in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, c++-cli, unique-ptr

I'm currently converting my instances of `auto_ptr` to `unique_ptr`, but I'm hitting an issue. It works great in the C++ part of the code, but when doing it in my managed C++/CLI layer (the software uses both C# and C++) I get link errors. It compiles fine, but it breaks at link time. There were never any issues with `auto_ptr`.

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010. Does anybody know of any issues with using `unique_ptr` in C++/CLI?

I've tried to sum up my issue in a piece of code below, but please be aware that the code below *actually compiles and works* (I checked that the ownership of the pointers get moved properly). I'm not getting linking errors when compiling this, but the code below is pure C++ and not C++/CLI. I just wanted to have a minimal example of how the code is constructed so the linker error makes more sense to read.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

namespace Test {

template< class T >
struct LinAlgPoint3 {
  LinAlgPoint3() { x = y = z = 0; };

  union {
    struct {T x,y,z;} ;
    T data_[3];
  };
};

class ContainerClass
{
public:
  void setUniquePtr(
    unique_ptr< vector< LinAlgPoint3< float > > > newUniquePtr1 ,
    unique_ptr< vector< unsigned char > > newUniquePtr2 )
  {
    m_uniquePtr1 = move(newUniquePtr1);
    m_uniquePtr2 = move(newUniquePtr2);
  }

private:
  unique_ptr< vector< LinAlgPoint3< float > > > m_uniquePtr1;
  unique_ptr< vector< unsigned char > > m_uniquePtr2;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  auto pos = unique_ptr< vector< LinAlgPoint3< float > > >( new vector< LinAlgPoint3< float > >() );
  auto name = unique_ptr< vector< unsigned char > >(new vector< unsigned char >());
  ContainerClass container;
  container.setUniquePtr(move(pos), move(name));
}

} //namespace Test
```

The error I get when linking is the following:

```
error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0018A5) "private: __cdecl std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > >::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > >(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > > const &)" (??0?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FAEAA@AEBV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > >::<MarshalCopy>(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > > *,class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > > *)" (?<MarshalCopy>@?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FSMXPEAV12@0@Z)
1>TestClass.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0018A6) "private: __cdecl std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > const &)" (??0?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FAEAA@AEBV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >::<MarshalCopy>(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > *,class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > *)" (?<MarshalCopy>@?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FSMXPEAV12@0@Z)
1>TestClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > const &)" (??0?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FAEAA@AEBV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > >::<MarshalCopy>(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > *,class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > > > *)" (?<MarshalCopy>@?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FSMXPEAV12@0@Z)
1>TestClass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > >::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > >(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > > const &)" (??0?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FAEAA@AEBV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __clrcall std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > >::<MarshalCopy>(class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > > *,class std::unique_ptr<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > >,struct std::default_delete<class std::vector<struct LinAlgPoint3<float>,class std::allocator<struct LinAlgPoint3<float> > > > > *)" (?<MarshalCopy>@?$unique_ptr@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@U?$default_delete@V?$vector@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@V?$allocator@U?$LinAlgPoint3@M@Test@@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@$$FSMXPEAV12@0@Z)
1>D:\Test\Test.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

As you can see (if you can get through the incredibly horrible messages) there are some references to MarshalCopy, something that makes me worry that C++/CLI might not support unique_ptr yet.

The layout of the software is

```
C# executable -> C++/CLI translation layer (dll) -> C++ dll
```

So the C++ dll compiles fine using unique_ptr, but the C++/CLI dll is unable to link properly.

I forgot to mention something quite important: If I use unique_ptr to a simpler datatype, for instance a string, it links successfully. For example:

```
  auto string1= unique_ptr< string >(new string(20000, 'S'));
  auto string2 = unique_ptr< string >(new string(20000, 'A'));
  string1= std::move(string2);
```

and I've also tried to make sure to use the variable so the compiler doesn't optimize it away.

**Edit:** I've just tested adding another external function that accepts a `unique_ptr<string>`, and I tried sending in the above `string1` and that breaks as well! So the issue must be between the generated DLLs, since the std::move() works well within each file/class.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose an issue when we only see the errors, not the code that created them. You said that this C++ code works, but your actual C++/CLI code doesn't. Can you write some C++/CLI code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I can try... Haven't written much C++/CLI from scratch in my days :)

Comment: Comment out all the move calls to get a clean compile.  Move semantics are a C++11 feature implemented by the C++ compiler.  Not by the C++/CLI compiler.  You could post to connect.microsoft.com to shake that tree.

Comment: I don't think it'll get a clean compile. If the C++/CLI compiler doesn't implement move semantics, there's no way `unique_ptr` could possibly work.

Comment: Then I get `error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`, just like I got in my small example above before adding the call to move().
Something I've forgotten to mention is that the code compiles if I use a `unique_ptr<double>` instead of the more advanced types above. I have to confirm that again though.

Comment: Edited the question to add some vital information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, don't know how relevant it is now, but I had exactly same problem with C++/CLI and solved it with taking r-value reference instead of value. I mean:
    void setUniquePtr(unique_ptr**&&** a, unique_ptr**&&** b)

This way it compiles though it's not a cleanest way to do things.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Reading through that complex error message, I think it's complaining that the `LinAlgPoint3` struct doesn't have a copy constructor. Try implementing the copy constructor, and maybe operators `=` and `==`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you for a good suggestion. You were right, the class was missing an assignment-operator as well as the copy constructor (it already had `==`), but adding them didn't fix the issue.. :(

Comment: I just added some more information at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass C++ objects between DLLs and expect it to work right.

Memory layout can be different in different modules.  Different allocators are almost certainly being used (this shoots down any C++ type that owns memory, including `string`, `vector`, and `unique_ptr`).

Use of pointers to pure virtual base classes can help with this.

Or, if you have the source code for the C++ part, try linking the C++ and C++/CLI into a single DLL, instead of referencing C++ code in a separate DLL.

Comment: But unique_ptr takes an implicit pointer to the destructor to be able to call the correct one based on type.

Comment: @AzP: It doesn't just take a pointer to the destructor, it's specialized for each deleter.  Which causes problems across module boundaries.